# Trying to open a section from the web.config spans a ConfigurationErrorsException: The entry KEY has already been added

Tags: asp.net, web-config, configuration-files, webconfigurationmanager

I'm trying to fetch some settings from my membership provider in my asp.net application (so that I don't have to duplicate the information in the appSettings section) but I am getting the following exception:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The entry 'MyMembershipProvider' has already been added. (C:\Inetpub\intranet-webapp\web.config line 53)
```

My code is the following:

```
var configurationManager = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/", "IntranetWebapp");
var section = (MembershipSection) configurationManager.GetSection("system.web/membership");
```

The exception is raised in the second line. I find it completely bizarre, since I am not trying to add any new information to the config file. Instead I'm just trying to retrieve it.

The contents of my config section:

```
<membership defaultProvider="IntranetApp">
  <providers>
    <add applicationName="IntranetApp"
         enableSearchMethods="true"
         connectionStringName="IntranetConnectionString"
         connectionUsername="CN=username,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users,OU=CompanyName,DC=CompanyName,DC=com"
         connectionPassword="********"
         name="MyIntranetMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Pablo

Comment: Could you post the contents of the Config section in question? Anonymised if you like ;)

Comment: @Zhaph don't know if it's useful but here it is...

Comment: Shouldn't your second line read: var section = (MembershipSection) configurationManager.GetSection("system.web/membership");?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the fix from my comment, I can't see anything wrong with your code - using the exact same thing (with a different value for the site property obviously) results in a populated section variable as I'd expect.

The only thing I can think of is that you're either doing something else with ConfigurationFile.Getsection, that is attempting to merge the data into your main setting, or by using the overload of OpenWebConfiguration that takes a site you've managed to open a web.config from a different area in the hierarchy into your site - do you have either multiple applications defined in IIS/.NET that would have conflicting values for their Membership setting?

Finally, shouldn't you DefaultProvider value read "MyIntranetMembershipProvider", which is the name of your provider, rather than "IntranetApp" which is the name of the application (in the provider's datastore).

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo when I was anonymizing my xml code. The provider declaration is all correct.
What it seems to me is that the GetSection method purpose is not to load the contents of the config file, but rather to change it.

Comment: Well, it's for reading and writing to the config file so it should work - also is your line for GetSection correct (as per my second comment). What aspects of the provider are you trying to avoid duplicating in the AppSettings?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this problem by doing what [*CzechDeveloper* did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6679286/2615152), in a related thread, with:

```
<clear />
```

**Important:**  This only worked for me when I put it directly above the nested element that was duplicating.

```
<sso>
  <stores>
    <clear />
    <store name="Store1" apiKey="abcd" />
    <store name="Store2" apiKey="efgh" />
  </stores>
</sso>
```

We *also* started seeing these problems when we started adding [virtual directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341882/2615152) as *therealsix* points out.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this same error after copying my site to a virtual directory under the same site. I guess there is some inheritance there.

I was able to get around it by adding this right before the line in question:

```
<remove name="MyMembershipProvider"/>
```

Comment: Yep, the way WebConfigurationManager works is that it pieces together each of the web.config files in the folder structure from where you called for it, back up to the root of the application, then into the various web.config and machine.config files in the framework configuration folder.