# ASP.NET error about connection string name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website with .net framework 4 and telerik 2012, when i uploaded my web site on the server one of my page has this error.

> The entry 'ConnectionString' has already been added.

for solving this err i use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679233/the-entry-has-already-been-added-error):

```
<remove name="ConnectionString" />
```

and after this line ,define my connection in web config. but this err apear :

> ** Method not found: 'System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceMapping.GetDefinition(System.String)'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceMapping.GetDefinition(System.String)'.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**

> {Note : this err just occurred on the server not in local } 
>   and when i removed this line : `<remove name="ConnectionString" />`   the first err apear again : The entry 'ConnectionString' has already been added.

What can I do now?

Comment: You've got two problems and when you solve the connection string problem the java script problem appears. It seems unlikely they are related and I would create a new question regarding the js problems.

Comment: the second problem occurred when the connection problem solved , and also it just occurred when load on server , but it worked good on local

Comment: There is another ConnectionString having the same name with your connectionString in the connection pool. Maybe you should check you IIS connection pool.

Comment: It seems to me there is framework issue, Make sure you have same framework on local as well on server machine. Also make sure your SP installed :)

Comment: [@Phong Vo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2197797/phong-vo) thank you. yes i have the same connection string name in my pool. But the second err didn't solve.I should instal framework 4.5. Maybe become true.

Comment: [@Microtechie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2440114/microtechie): I told that i changed the framework in my project by right click on it and change target frame work from 4.5 to 4.and the server target framework is 4.and SP was installed.

Comment: please show the <connectionStrings> section of your web.config file

Comment: the err of connection is solve but the second err not, Method not found: 'System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceMapping.GetDefinition(System.String)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check framework version on your web server, it should be 4.5. In 4.0 GetDefinition function do not have overload which accpet a string param only. Keep following entry in web.config as it has nothing to do with other error you are getting.

```
<remove name="ConnectionString" />
```

Comment: at first my framework version was 4.5 and server was 4. i changed my web site framework from 4.5 to 4. do you think the reason of my problem is this?

Comment: @hony Could be the problem, please check <assemblies> section of your local web.config if it refers to correct version of System.Web.Extensions.dll.

Comment: if your webserver has 4.5 available change its framework version to 4.5.

Comment: if you can provide full stack trace here. Need to identify which code is calling this method.