# The entry has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, webmatrix

All my Razors views have this error:

> The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message:
>
> The entry 'DefaultConnection' has already been added.

Now, as you can see in my connection string configuration, I don't have the connection string name repeated:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\foo;Initial Catalog=aspnet-foo-20130212133051;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ServiDeskConnection" connectionString="Data Source=fooo;Initial Catalog=mdb;User Id=foo;Password=fooo;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="mdbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ExternalData.ExternalContext.csdl|res://*/Models.ExternalData.ExternalContext.ssdl|res://*/Models.ExternalData.ExternalContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=foo;initial catalog=mdb;user id=foo;password=foo_prod01;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="SisInfoInventoryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ExternalData.Inventory.csdl|res://*/Models.ExternalData.Inventory.ssdl|res://*/Models.ExternalData.Inventory.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\foo;initial catalog=foo;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I already tried to use `<Clear/>`, but it is worse, because it said that I don't have any connection.

I tried to unload the project of the same solution, but it stills did not work.

Note that when I build the project, it works well.

<sub>(This has been answered several times, but none of the solutions had worked for me.)</sub>

Comment: try adding `<Clear\>` before first element in connectionStrings element

Comment: It looks like `<Clear/>` and `<Remove name="DefaultConnection"/>` both before all `add` should do the trick.

Comment: Doesn't work it does not find any connection string in my web.config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The entry '' has already been added error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679233/the-entry-has-already-been-added-error)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

After the `<providers>` and before the first `<add....>` node, add a `<clear />` node. That will fix it!!

Or it can be in web.config that is parent to this one. Just add the below code before you add it again.

```
<remove name="DefaultConnection" />
```

Alternatively, clear all connection strings using

```
<clear />
```

I would suggest you rename DefaultConnection to something else like MyAppServices.

Comment: Sorryy but first I don't have declare any providers and already tried the clear but it doesn't work

Comment: ok and Also worth checking that you do not have the Connection String added at a higher level, e.g. the MACHINE.CONFIG file. @Jorge

Comment: Checked too but no, it does not have a connection with the same name

Comment: I would suggest you rename  DefaultConnection to something else like MyAppServices @Jorge

Comment: `<clear/>` dirty and naughty little fix that - especially if multiple developers work on the same file and end up breaking your environment every time they check in some bogus `web.config`. This fix did wonders for my local environment

Comment: Just changing the name to MyAppServices worked for me - but now I have a 404 error :-(