# how connect both PostgreSQL and timescale databases into ASP.NET MVC web.config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

I created a project "SmartHome" using the ASP.NET MVC. I used two types of databases;

- PostgreSQL
- TIMESCALE

Here, I integrate the TIMESCALE with the PostgreSQL.

I connected the PostgreSQL with ASP.NET MVC and it is working fine. the connection string as below.

```
<add name="SmartHomeContext" 
connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=smarthome;
User Id=postgres;Password=postdata;" providerName="Npgsql" />
```

here database names of;

- PostgreSQL = smarthome
- TIMESCALE = smarthomeData

My problem is " **How TIMESCALE database connect to work with same "SmartHome" database in the ASP.NET MVC ?** "

I tried the connection string for TIMESCALE as below.

```
<add name="SmartHomeContext" 
connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=smarthomeData;
User Id=postgres;Password=postdata;" providerName="Npgsql" />
```

but it shows the below error:
**"The entry 'SmartHomeContext' has already been added."**

Please help me or guide me, I am very new to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The entry '' has already been added error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679233/the-entry-has-already-been-added-error)

Answer (score 0):

Above error ("The entry 'SmartHomeContext' has already been added.") was solved and the connection also done. the steps are followed as below;

- **Web.config file** : add a another connection string for TIMESCALE database as  **"SmartHomeContext1"**. In the below code snippet, **third connection string**.

  ```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source= 
  (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SmartHome- 
  20181019034449.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SmartHome-20181019034449;Integrated 
  Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  <add name="SmartHomeContext" 
  connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=smarthome;User 
  Id=postgres;Password=postdata;" providerName="Npgsql" />

  <add name="SmartHomeContext1" 
  connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=smarthomeData;User 
  Id=postgres;Password=postdata;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ```
- create "**timescalecontext.cs**" file in the Model as attached image.
  [timescalecontext.cs in the Models folder in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpL7d.png)
- already I created a table in the database "smarthomeData" as attached image.
  [timescale database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pprqE.png)
- then, code the "**timescalecontext.cs**" file as below.

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Data.Entity;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;

  namespace SmartHome.Models
  {
  public class timescalecontext : DbContext
  {

  public timescalecontext() : base("name=SmartHomeContext1")
  {
  }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }

  public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SmartHome.Models.DeviceReading> DeviceReadings { get; set; }
  public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SmartHome.Models.Event> Events { get; set; }
  }

  }
  ```
- since the controller file already created before make the above connection, change the code matched with the Dbcontext as below:

  ```
  namespace SmartHome.Controllers
  {
  public class DeviceReadingsController : Controller
  {
  private timescalecontext db = new timescalecontext();
  ```

after all that, It worked. Hope, this will be helpful.